# ASP.NET OAuth: How is access token generated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

I'm learning about access tokens and OAuth in ASP.NET from [this great tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) ...and I have a question.

In the linked article, the author says:

> Now generating the token happens behind the scenes when we call “context.Validated(identity)”.

What exactly is happening behind the scenes? It's just that I'm curious, I don't like working with black boxes and I like knowing the code behind since it often helps me understanding the bigger picture.

I'd like to see the part responsible for the token generation. I've found that `Validated` basically [just sets some properties](http://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/3.0.0-beta1-30329-853-dev/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/Provider/BaseValidatingContext.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth) but I can't find where is the access token string generated.

Also, **just for the sake of experimentation and learning** (so please don't yell at me for "inventing my own security"), is it possible to define your own way to encode/decode those tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it!

In `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` you can specify `AccessTokenFormat` propert of type `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>`.

The interface `ISecureDataFormat<T>` is pretty simple, it's just two methods: `Protect(T data)` and `Unprotect(string protectedText)`. So if you want your own access token format, just implement this interface and assign a new instance as your AccessTokenFormat.

The default implementation seems to be `SecureDataFormat` ([source here](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightlyrelease/Project/Microsoft.Owin.Security/2.0.0-rtw2-20905-616-rel/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5/Microsoft.Owin.Security/Microsoft.Owin.Security/DataHandler/SecureDataFormat.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.Owin.Security)) which uses `IDataSerializer<T>`, `IDataProtector` and `ITextEncoder` ... it uses the serializer to serialize the object to bytes, those are then put through the protector and that result finally goes through the text encoder... Unprotect is the same thing just in opossite direction.

Okay then, what is the default implementation of `IDataSerializer<T>` and `IDataProtector`? There are [three serializers in OWIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.datahandler.serializer%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) and it sure seems the one used to serialize tickets is the [TicketSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.datahandler.serializer.ticketserializer%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) ([source here](http://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightlyrelease/Project/Microsoft.Owin.Security/2.1.0-rc1-21208-727-rel/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5/Microsoft.Owin.Security/Microsoft.Owin.Security/DataHandler/Serializer/TicketSerializer.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.Owin.Security))

`IDataProtector` seems to be implemented as `DpapiDataProtector` ([source](https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightlyrelease/Project/Microsoft.Owin.Security/2.0.0-rtw2-20905-616-rel/Release/.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5/Microsoft.Owin.Security/Microsoft.Owin.Security/DataProtection/DpapiDataProtector.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.Owin.Security)) which uses [class of the same name from a System.Security.Cryptography namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.security.cryptography.dpapidataprotector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and that seems to be closed source thought the Protect and Unprotect methods are inherited from [DataProtector class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dataprotector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I didn't know what "Dpapi" is so I googled and discovered a thing called *Windows Data Protection* in [this article from 2001](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx)...

I hope this will be useful for someone else.

Comment: Hey, do you know which `ITextEncoder` is used by default?